# How can I convert this JavaScript recursive function to an iterative one?

Tags: javascript, recursion

How can I change this recursive function into iterative function? I'm learning JavaScript and want to do this exercise as a practice.

```
function squirt(n, g) {
  if (!g) {
    // Take an initial guess at the square root
    g = n / 2.0;
  }

  var d = n / g; // Divide our guess into the number
  var ng = (d + g) / 2.0; // Use average of g and d as our new guess

  if (g == ng) {          
    // The new guess is the same as the old guess; further guesses
    // can get no more accurate so we return this guess
    return g;
  }

  // Recursively solve for closer and closer approximations of the square root
  return squirt(n, ng);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this site isn't for doing your home works.you can start learning JavaScript from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and use the **exit condition of your recursion** as the **exit condition from your `while` loop**

```
function squirt( n, g ) 
{   
  var d, ng, g = n / 2.0; //initialize g
  while ( g != ( d + g ) / 2.0 ) //convert g==ng to this
  {
     d = n / g; 
     g = ( d + g ) / 2.0;     
  }

  return g; //return g
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function squirt( n, g ) 
{   
  var d, ng, g = n/2.0;
  while ( g != ( d + g ) / 2.0 )
  {
     d = n / g; 
     g = ( d + g ) / 2.0;     
  }
  return g;
}

console.log( squirt(4) );
console.log( squirt(5) );
console.log( squirt(6) );
console.log( squirt(7) );
console.log( squirt(8) );
console.log( squirt(9) );
console.log( squirt(10) );
```

Comment: @CountryboyOmEr Glad that it has worked for you. You should accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.

Comment: im new member here, so i cant upvote yet. sorry

Comment: You can accept the answer though so that it help the others.

Comment: I apologise for the downvote, but this question was so nakedly lazy, that I think we should refrain from answering until a semblance of effort is made. Until we do that, the community will continue to be beset with help vampires who know they can get other people to work for free, reducing the signal-to-noise ratio for everyone. In this case, your very high reputation level suggests to me that you know this, but you post anyway. Would you consider encouraging an OP to make an initial effort next time?

Comment: @halfer You don't have to apologize, but I have seen far worst questions where **1)** OP doesn't event share a single line of code **2)** Post questions which are too broad **3)** Questions which are not understandable... Not trying to justify OP's lack of their own effort or research... just that maybe my own standards of **good question** could be lower than yours, possibly due to my own experience on SO. And yes, I usually do ask OP for showing their attempt with a stack-snippet myself.

Comment: I see your point, but judging by the comments, I was not the only one who saw it as a "convert this for me" post. It may yet still close as too broad for that reason, IMO.

Comment: @halfer sure, fair enough.